# Get the 1,000,000,000th digit in the sequence "12345678910111213..."

Tags: php

i try to get the 1000000th digit from a consecutive number like this: `1234567891011121314151617......`

After waiting for a minute, I got `3`, which is the 1,000,000th digit, but when I try to get the 1,000,000,000th digit, I got this message:

> [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 40009728 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\get\new.php on line
>   4391

This is my code:

```
<?php
$tot = 1000000000;
$i = 0;
$j = 1;
$a = array();
do{
    $length = strlen((string)$j);
    $str = str_split((string)$j);
    if($length == 1){
        if($i == $tot - 1){
        $a[$i] = $j;
        }
    $i++;
    $j++;
    }
    else{
        for($o = 1;$o<=$length;$o++){
            if($i==$tot){
                break;
            }
                if($i == $tot -1){
                $a[$i] = $str[$o - 1];
                }
            $i++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
while($i<$tot);

echo print_r($a);
?>
```

how can php generate the 1,000,000,000th digit when it cannot generate 1,000,000,000 numbers?

Comment: seriously... are you complaining that you aren't allowed to waste 1GB of memory with digits?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i just want to solve a puzzle with that consecutive number and find out 1000000000th digit,

Comment: for example: 123456789101112131415.... the 12th digit is 1, the 15th digit is 2, the 3rd digit is 3,

Comment: you know there are [built in functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to find the nth or more character from a string... which you could treat a number as...

Comment: Even if you want to iterate over the previous 999999999 digits (you don't have to), there's no need to remember them, only how many there have been.

Comment: @serakfalcon said string would have to weight 1GB...

Comment: lol 7.5 GB to be exact. It's a little bit crazy...

Comment: hint: The first 9 numbers have one digit each, the next 90 numbers have two digits each, the next 90 numbers have three digits each...

Comment: if i use string function, it got fatal error message too

Comment: BTW... if you're willing to go with Haskell, `concat(map show [1..]) !! (10^9)` is pretty slow (but still way faster than PHP - 3 minutes in interpreted code to get the billionth digit; I got the millionth digit in 210 ms), but it's memory efficient.

Comment: @user3686346 Consider `$n` as your number sequence in string format and try echoing `$n{1000000000 - 1}`.  You should get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to optimize your algorithm to find the Nth digit of the series 123...9101112.....100101102......

1. Do not store the numbers in an array, that would create memory limit issues.

There are then two easy ways to solve this problem:

1/ Run a loop, keep adding digits of each number, lets call it **sum** , when you add number of digits of next number in loop ,say **ndigits** ,  if sum+ndigits is more than the N ( the digit required), you stop, and check for (Nth-sum) digit in current number.

**demo** : http://codepad.org/Dekq4bCW

```
<?php
function findDigit($n)
{ 
  $sum = $num =  0;
  do{
      $num += 1;
      $sum += strlen($num);
  }while($n > $sum);

  $numStr = (string)($num);
  $dig = $numStr[$n - ($sum-strlen($numStr)) - 1] ;
  echo "Digit at ".$n." is : ".$dig."\n";
}

for($i=9;$i<=15;$i++)
{
   findDigit($i);
}

?>
```

2/ Since the pattern of digits is already known i.e. 9 single digits, then double digits, then triple digits etc.  You can figure out a generalized formula to give you digit in Nth place in a single call.

Comment: its may be error if we find the 1000000000th digits

Comment: @user3686346 No,it will not. Has been tested for that input.